# How do you Build and Run in Xcode with more than one .c file in the directory

Tags: c, xcode, build, compilation

For instance, if I have two helloworld programs, hello1.c and hello2.c in the same directory, Xcode says Build Failed when I try to run. If I delete and leave only one .c file, then it runs fine.

Comment: Xcode probably says Build Failed, because you got more than one main() function in these files (one in each), delete the main function in one of these files or rename it to something like main_two() (or a name, that actually makes sense ;) If that's not the problem try posting the error message you get, we can't do magic :)

Comment: That's correct! So c doesn't need a main method/function to work? I know in Java you must have main()

Comment: It absolutely does, your problem is not that you don't have one, but that you have TWO, which is one too much, because the compiler doesn't know which one to start in the beginning (which of them is the **main** one?).